# Virus Infection Affecting Other Users

Tags: virus

I recently had my computer infected by a virus on an administrator account that installed a bunch of scamming programs and changed my shortcuts to open on a scam browser page called snap.do. I was wondering if this virus would have affected other users shortcuts and infected their files.

edit: I am on Windows 10. It came about as a result of me installing a file without checking the list of optional additional programs it would install with it. After noticing the changes to my browser and random popups, I checked my installed programs and found a list of 7 or so programs that had been installed without me being aware. They all had sketchy names, something like PCCleaner and GetGreatDeals.

Comment: did you also need help un-hijacking the shortcuts?

Comment: @GmanSmith no thanks, I managed to fix it by editing shortcut path in properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Once the administrator account on a system is compromised you need to assume the whole system is compromised - and it would be possible to modify parts of the filesystem "owned by" other users.